# Splash image is not displayed on cordova-1.7 in Android

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I upgraded cordova from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 on existing Android project and the splash image of this app had not been displayed since then.

I upgraded the project by exchanging cordova.jar and cordoba.js.
The splash images (splash.png) are located under res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-ldpi and res/drawable-mdpi respectively and these are configured in onCreate() of Activity as below.

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

What can be considered as a cause?

Comment: I did change the splashscreen code around a bit but it should still work as normally. http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html

Comment: Thanks, I missed interval for loadUrl() and the splash image is displayed by providing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi  have you provided time interval for it . plz check the syntax

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/your1stpage.html",3000/*time interval*/);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash2x);
```

try it
you have given incomplete information so if the problem repeats plz post some code

Comment: Thanks, the splash image is displayed by providing interval.